# Streaming and Recording Protocol

Tags: streaming, audio-streaming, audio-recording, recording

What is an open source, well-documented audio (video is not required) streaming (from the server) protocol that also supports **recording** (to the server), that I should use for a completely new application?

- RTMP is not an option
- This protocol must have a client library for AC3/AC2

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [SHOUTcast](http://www.shoutcast.com/broadcast-tools)?  Sounds like it will work perfect for your application.

As far as recording the stream goes, you can use something like [StreamRipper](http://streamripper.sourceforge.net/), or even WGET.

No special client library necessary, as it is compatible with HTTP.  The only thing you have to worry about is your client keeping audio buffer around after it has been played, but there are many solutions to that, especially with AS3.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Red5](http://www.red5.org/). It's open source and has a [recorder](http://www.red5-recorder.com/), also open source.

If you are OK with spending few dollars, have a look at [Wowza Media Server](http://www.wowzamedia.com) too.